# Double new line as delimiter in awk and tail function

Tags: bash, awk, tail

I need to separate a text file which looks like this

```
1
00:01:03:321 --> 00:01:04:321
 Randomtext1

2
00:02:03:321 --> 00:03:04:321
 Randomtext2
Still random text2
3rd line of randomtext2

3
00:04:03:321 --> 00:05:04:321
 Randomtext3
Stillrand
```

To blocks including ordinal number line, timers line, content lines and then 
delete ordinal numbers line.
By separating code to blocks looking like this I mean that I want to make all those lines as 1 record (so it could be easier to delete first two(pure new line and ordinal number line))
This is code:

```
#!/bin/bash
name=text.sub
name2=text2.sub
awk '
BEGIN {FS="\n\n";

}
{ 
tail -n+1 $1;

}' $name > $name2
```

expected output will be

```
00:01:03:321 --> 00:01:04:321
 Randomtext1
00:02:03:321 --> 00:03:04:321
 Randomtext2
Still random text2
3rd line of randomtext2
00:04:03:321 --> 00:05:04:321
 Randomtext3
Stillrand
```

Comment: Please add expected output and clarify: *To blocks including ordinal number line, ... and then delete ordinal numbers line*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR%4~/^[23]$/' file
00:01:03:321 --> 00:01:04:321
 Randomtext1
00:02:03:321 --> 00:03:04:321
 Randomtext2
```

If that's not what you want then edit your question to provide more realistic sample input/output.

Answer (score 4):

I would treat each section like:

```
1
00:01:03:321 --> 00:01:04:321
 Randomtext1
```

as an individual record.

You can play around with record and field separators to achieve that, like this:

```
awk '{$1=""}1' RS='' FS='\n' OFS='\n' file
```

- `RS=''` is the input record separator. `''` has a special meaning, it means `\n\n`
- `FS='\n'` sets the input field separator to newline
- `OFS=`\n` sets the output field separator to newline

The program `{$1=""}` erases the first field (the number) and `1` prints the record.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with this awk script:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { FS = "\n"
        RS = "\n\n" 
      }

      { print $2
        print $3 
      }
```

Run it like this: `awk -f script.awk text.sub > text2.sub`

By defining the field separator `FS` as newline and the record separator `RS` as double newline we get the fields into the usual `$1, $2, $3`.

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
1
00:01:03:321 --> 00:01:04:321
 Randomtext1

2
00:02:03:321 --> 00:03:04:321
 Randomtext2
```

**Script**

```
 awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n"}{printf "%s\n%s\n",$2,$3}' file
```

**Output**

```
00:01:03:321 --> 00:01:04:321
 Randomtext1
00:02:03:321 --> 00:03:04:321
 Randomtext2
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
$ sed -n '2~4p;3~4p' file

00:01:03:321 --> 00:01:04:321
 Randomtext1
00:02:03:321 --> 00:03:04:321
 Randomtext2
```

print every 4th line starting lines 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you exactly want to do, but according to your desired output, this command produces the same result:

```
awk '!/^[0-9]*$/' text.sub
```